# Spark: IOException, Stream closed during logging

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ioexception

I am trying to use Spark to count the frequency of anchor texts in Wikipedia XML dump.

The input/output:

- Input: list of anchor texts
- Output: list of (anchor text, frequency) pairs

The current solution:

```
anchor_texts.map(
    key => (key, 1)
).reduceByKey {
    case (acc, i) => acc + i
}
```

None of the jobs succeeds. After checking the worker log, I the following error:

```
15/12/17 17:28:33 ERROR FileAppender: Error writing stream to file /cs/work/home/hxiao/spark-related/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20151217163507-0000/28/stderr

java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:272)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender.appendStreamToFile(FileAppender.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileAppender.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1.run(FileAppender.scala:38)
```

**What I find strange is:**

Before this stage, I also used Spark to collect the mapping from page title to page id. Everything works fine. However, for this stage, it crashes.

Some version information:

- Spark: 1.5.2
- Scala: 2.10.5
- Mode: cluster mode

Spark configuration:

```
SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=8G
SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=8G
SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=8
```

**What I also find strange is**

If I run this program on a smaller dataset, things work fine. However, if on the whole Wikipedia, then the above errors.

Answer (score 0):

what is the input path? spark doesn't actually read the file into rdd before other operations, try to use spark shell and run code like

val rdd = sc.textFile("path")

val sample = rdd.take(1)

to see if the path is accessible